# Does Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) know everything?

Tags: prophet-muhammad

Recently I've seen in an Facebook page that Hazrat Muhammad (pbuh) Doesn't know everything. He doesn't know **Gayeb**. But many person oppose this.. They said that Prophet (pbuh) knows everything and **Gayeb**. If anyone think that he doesn't know every mystery of creation it may cause a hamper of his **Faith**.

I need an answer..

Comment: بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم:- و النجم إذا هوى (1) ما ضل صاحبكم و ما غوى (2) و ما ينطق عن الهوى (3) إن هو إلا وحي يوحى (4) علمه شديد القوى(5)...صدق الله العظيم

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bismillah

Assalamu `alaykum my dear brother, your saying *many person oppose this* is based on evidences and strong proof. Without authentic evidence, no one is to decide something relating to deen.

Coming back to your question, I will provide you with evidences and without being biased, if you have stronger proofs that he (sallallahu alayhi wasallam) knows everything, please feel free to share - but they have to be authentic (either from Qur'an or an Authentic hadith)

Let me start with gayeb, part of knowing gayeb is knowledge of the hour, when will it be;

If you read [very first hadith of Sahih Muslim](http://muflihun.com/muslim/1/1) (quoting only part of it since it is a lengthy hadith) -

> He (the enquirer) again said: Inform me about the hour (of the Doom). He (the Holy Prophet) remarked: **One who is asked knows no more than the one who is inquiring** (about it).

So Rasullulah (sallallahu alayhi wasallam) did not know about when the hour will be. But he (sallallahu alayhi wasallam) did mention some signs of it (it's in same hadith so you may read it)

---

OK let me change my way; let me quote few points in short; so people can answer in detail about each point

- Say: "None in the heavens and the earth knows the Ghaib (Unseen) except Allaah, nor can they perceive when they shall be resurrected" - [An-Naml 27:65](http://muflihun.com/27/65)
- And with Him are the keys of the unseen; none knows them except Him - [An-An'am 6:59](http://muflihun.com/6/59)
- Indeed, Allah [alone] has knowledge of the Hour and sends down the rain and knows what is in the wombs. And no soul perceives what it will earn tomorrow, and no soul perceives in what land it will die. Indeed, Allah is Knowing and Acquainted - [Luqman 31:34](http://muflihun.com/31/34)
- 'Aisha (rady allahu `anhaa) further said, "And whoever tells you that the Prophet knows what is going to happen tomorrow, is a liar." - [Bukhari](http://muflihun.com/bukhari/60/378)

Someone may come and talk about another ayah - [Surat ‘Al–`Imran 3:179](http://muflihun.com/3/179?tafid=1592) I would suggest you go and read tafsir of this ayah in that case

For further details:

- https://muflihun.com/articles/knowledge-of-unseen/
- Whether Jinn knows unseen? Read [Reality of Magic and It's cure in Islam](https://muflihun.com/articles/jinn#knowledge-of-unseen) specifically **Knowledge of Unseen** section
- http://islamqa.info/en/101968

Wassalam

Comment: Another hadith where the Prophet indicated incomplete knowledge relates to grafting of trees: [Sahih Muslim 2363](http://sunnah.com/muslim/43/186): "They said: You said so and so. Thereupon he said: You have better knowledge (of a technical skill) in the affairs of the world."  (And wasn't the Prophet [illiterate](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/was-the-prophet-illiterate)?)

Answer (score 0):

`Quran 27:65` Say, None in the heavens and earth knows the unseen except Allah...

`Quran 72:26` [Allah, he is] Knower of the unseen, and He does not disclose His [knowledge of the] unseen to anyone

`Quran 81:24` And he [Muhammad] is not a withholder of [knowledge of] the unseen.

`Quran 3:44`  That is from the news of the unseen which We reveal to you, [O Muhammad]. And you were not with them when they cast their pens as to which of them should be responsible for Mary (Mariam). Nor were you with them when they disputed.

Believe in Quran and Hadeeth and not in heard stories or your ancestors believe.

Answer (score -1):

Its is the belief  of the Ahle Sunnat wal Jamat to believe that he (saw) had Ilm ul Ghayb granted from the almighty and that only knowledge is bestowed by he who created everything

Answer (score -1):

According to Sunni view, Holy Prophet has knowledge of unseen.

As said in Holy Quran:

> “These are the tidings of Unseen that We reveal to you in secret”.
>   Surah-Ale-Imran, verse 44.
>
> “Nor will He disclose to you the secrets of the Unseen. But He chooses of His Apostles (For the purpose)”
>   Surah-Ale-Imran, verse 179.
>
> “The Knower of Unseen reveals not His secret to anyone. Except to His chosen Messengers”.
>   Surah-Al-Jinn, verse 26.

Imam Bukhari writes :

> Prophet Muhammad (May Allah bless him and grant him peace) stood up in one meeting and he started to tell us about events from the beginning of this world to the end and he told us about heaven and hell and about the people who were going to hell and who were going to heaven and what will be their places in heaven and hell. Of course, some people remember what he told us and some people have forgotten. 
>   (Bukhari, Chapter Bada-Ul-Khalq.)

Imam Muslim writes that:

> The Prophet Muhammad (May Allah bless him and grant him peace) led the Fajr prayer and then sat on the pulpit, and until Zuhr he told the people of the things about the Unseen. After Zuhr, he sat on the pulpit and continued until Asar, then sat on the pulpit and continued until Maghrib prayer. He even informed of the dwellers of Paradise and Hell. 
>   (Muslim chapter on Fadial).

Imam Ahmad bin Hanbal quotes the following narration which provides more evidence on the Prophets knowledge :

> The Prophet (May Allah bless him and grant him peace) stated, “I have seen my Lord, He put His hands upon my chest, after which everything appeared before me and I recognized everything. 
>   [Musnad Ahmad Ibn Hanbal, vol 5, page 243]

you people can found alot of references from Quran and Ahadith, but this depend upon your believes how much you believe in your prophet.